# Ошибка при выполнении деления на ноль

Tags: python, python-3.x

Мне надо написать простейший калькулятор, который принимает в первые два инпута числовые значения, а в третью - операцию. По условию задачи, если одно из двух чисел равно нулю (0.0), а операцией является деление, то должна выводиться строка "Деление на 0!" Но при попытке запустить код со этими условиями, выдается ошибка о делении на ноль. Как это пофиксить?[image: Не обращайте внимание на этот псевдокод, я только учусь.]

Comment: Текстовую информацию (код, вывод, текст ошибки) нужно добавлять в текстовом виде, а не в виде скриншотов.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

input не нужно превращать в str, потому что он по определению возвращает строку.

```
a = float ( input("Первое число >>> ") )
b = float ( input("Второе число >>> ") )

oper = input( "Операция? (+, -, *, /, 'div', 'mod') >>> " )

c = ""

if oper == "/":
    c = "Деление на ноль!" if b == 0 else a / b
elif oper == "mod":
    c = "Деление на ноль!" if b == 0 else a % b
elif oper == "div":
    c = "Деление на ноль!" if b == 0 else a // b
elif oper == "*":
    c = a * b
elif oper == "+":
    c = a + b
elif oper == "-":
    c = a - b
else:
    c = "Выбрана неверная операция!"

print( c )
input()
```

P.s. Считается хорошим тоном добавлять код в виде текста, а не картинки) Чтобы люди могли скопировать и "пощупать" его у себя.

Comment: Спасибо, буду знать.

Answer (score 0):

Кусок кода, для проверки того что нужно:

И это нужно написать сразу а после писать остальные условия

```py
a = float(input())
b = float(input())
c = str(input())
if (c=="DIV" or c=="/" or c=="MOD") and not a==0 and not b== 0:
    print("sf")
else:
    print("Деление на 0!")
```

Comment: зачем and not a==0?!

Comment: @МихаилАлексеевич для того чтобы оба числа если не 0, то выполнилось условие. А если хотя бы 1 из них ==0 то вывелось сообщение

Comment: Вы не чувствуете разницу между "деление нуля" и "деление на ноль"?

Comment: @МихаилАлексеевич По условию задачи, если одно из двух чисел равно нулю (0.0), то выводиться: Деление на 0

Answer (score 0):

Как я понял, Вы выводите операцию 'c' с данными переменными 'a' и 'b'. Рекомендую Вам написать if-elif, а не if, для однозначной работы.

А про Ваш вопрос:

```py
if c == '/':
    if b != 0:
        print(a / b)
    else:
        print('Деление на 0!')
elif c == 'mod':
    if b != 0:
        print(a % b)
    else:
        print('Деление на 0!')
elif c == 'div':
    if b != 0:
        print(a // b)
    else:
        print('Деление на 0!')
# и так далее
```